# How can I make multer parse a client request sent with form-data properly?

Tags: node.js, express, axios, multer, form-data

I want to transfer data from a client to a server computer where both of them are using `Node.js`. On client I'm using the libraries `axios` and `form-data`. On the server I'm using `express` and `multer`...

The client code that I'm using is the following:

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const axios = require('axios');

let form = new FormData();
form.append("user", "someuser");

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:9996/data',
    data: form
})
.then(function (response) {
     console.log(response.status);
})
.catch(function (response) {
     console.log(response.status);
});
```

And the server code is the following:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer  = require('multer')

const app = express();
const upload = multer();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/data', upload.none(), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200)
})

const port = 9996;
app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`running on port ${port}`)
})
.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('stopped')
})
```

This code is functional and I manage to get the `form` `JSON` that I have created on the client as a request message on the server. However, the output of my `req.body` on the server is as the following:

```
{ '----------------------------926328179431047129531240\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name':
   '"user"\r\n\r\nsomeuser\r\n----------------------------926328179431047129531240--\r\n' }
```

This output is not formatted as a JSON object as I expected. Isn't the parameter `upload.none()` from `multer` supposed to parse `req.body` as a JSON? **Does anyone know what I'm getting wrong here and if there's any other parameter that I need to change in order to make the output on req.body to be formatted as a JSON object?**

---

**Observation:**  I know that if I create this JSON manually with `const form = {"user":"someuser"}` I will have the output as an object on `req.body` on the server. However, I'm using `form-data` because on my original code I plan to read a huge file with `createReadStream` on the client and write it with `createWriteStream` on the server, and the library `form-data` is the solution that I found to make `axios` support streaming of data.

Comment: This looks like multi-part form data which means you need some middleware beyond what `body-parser` can do in order to parse that for you.  [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is a common one.

Comment: Or, maybe change the client so it isn't sending `multipart/form-data` as I don't see why you're forcing that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've removed both the `contentType` and the `config` here of my `axios` parameters and they actually make no difference on the outcome of the server... I'm checking the `Multer` solution by now, thanks!

Comment: yeah you use multer or an equivalent solution here

Comment: try ```console.log(req.body)```  & ```console.log(req.files)``` inside multer upload function. If i remember ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for what you see is that `multer` **only parses the request when `content-type` header is set to `multipart/form-data`**. You are not setting request headers so the request is send using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multer` ignores it and `body-parser` do the parsing instead.

To fix it set headers on your request like this:

```js
const FormData = require("form-data");
const axios = require("axios");

let form = new FormData();
form.append("user", "someuser");
// form.append("my_buffer", Buffer.alloc(10)); // or actual image

axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/data",
  data: form,
  headers: form.getHeaders()
})
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
  })
  .catch(function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! It was such a simple detail but I didn't figure out.

Comment: @RafaelMuynarsk No problem ;) If you can mark it as an answer it would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the previous answers (@Michal Levy) already mentions that `multer` requires the enctype="multipart/form-data" declaration in your client-side HTML form.
This is the example straight from the docs:

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>
```

Next, your question on `multer.null()` (probably it's a statement) that should return a JSON object in the req.body - I think this is *incorrect.*

[Based again on the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html), `multer.null()` should be used if the form contains text only fields:

> In case you need to handle a text-only multipart form, you should use the .none() method.

Therefore, this suggests you might not get JSON in the req.body out-of-the-box. 
Furthermore, the output you log in your snippet is likely to come from the request object, and not from `multer` itself. I will get to this in one second.

This is a snippet that will show you how to use correctly `multer` server-side and how to log your results at a very high-level, without taking into account memory storage etc.

1. Go back to your client-side code and make sure you have an HTML form with the correct `enctype`, else `multer` wont't work.
2. remove your `multer.null()` method since it does nothing to really help you but allowing you to load just text-only forms, not JSON pre-formatted outputs.
3. include something like this instead:

   ```
   const multer = require("multer");
   const upload = multer().single("name_field_in_your_form"); // this is the fieldname in your form if you want to upload a single file only
   ```
4. Inside the module that handles the form, let `multer` handles the error rather than leaving this to `express`...like this you catch the errors at load time:

   ```
   upload(req, res, function (err) {
     if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
       console.log("MultiError occured when uploading");
       return;
     }

     else if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       return;
     }
   ```
5. Stringify the fields and get the data you want from the `multer` middleware:

   const { fieldname1example, fieldname2example } = JSON.stringify(**req.body**);
   const yourMulterFile = **req.file**;
6. log the yourMulterFile variable and convert to JSON the data you are interested in. 
   If you are interested in the file itself for further processing, look at the `.buffer` property which returns as the name suggest a buffer of the file uploaded.

Let me know if this does not address or clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const storage = multer.memoryStorage() ;
let upload = multer({
    storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        //if (mimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
          return cb(null, true);
        //}
        //cb('File type not allowed', false);
    }
}).any();

router
    .post('/',(req,res)=>{
        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                // An error occurred when uploading to server memory
                return res.status(502).json(err) ;
            }
            console.log(req.body);
            console.log(req.files);
....
```