# Not able to post form-data in node in index.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node and express.
So basically, I removed `users.js` from the routes folder created by express-generator and was trying to execute everything in `index.js`.

Usually, I would have to do `form action="/users/form-data"` but since in app.js, we have

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

So, I instead did `form action="/form-data"` and

`index.js` pasted the code from `users.js`

```
router.post("/form-data", function(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.body);
  variable1 = req.body.somedata;
  res.redirect('newpage');
});
```

But the console.log shows undefind and there is error that `cannot read property somedata of undefined`.

Nothing is wrong in any other files but I only edited the form action line.
So, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT

If it concerns, my routes folder is actually under a "server" folder, but I accordingly edited to `var indexRouter = require('./server/routes/index');`

Comment: did you add middleware that would parse formdata?

Comment: are you using a bodyParser?

Comment: @mr.loop add `app.use(express.json());` and `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` to your `app.js`

Comment: @MohamedOraby express.json was already there and turning urlencoded to true also didn't made any difference

Comment: @mr.loop sorry to parse form-data you need to use multer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014876/how-can-i-make-multer-parse-a-client-request-sent-with-form-data-properly

Comment: @MohamedOraby I added an edit if it matters

Comment: If the console.log in the route is logging then the route was being called correctly, you just need a bodyparser to parse the form-data like `mutler`

Comment: @MohamedOraby but I didn't needed anything in the the case where I was posting to users.js, why is that

Comment: If you were posting JSON you have `express,json()` parser meanwhile form-data is not JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edits and reasoning were correct, but only the form itself was lacking some crucial tags